# How can I avoid evolution script creation and execution in Play framework 2.1?

Tags: database, playframework, playframework-2.1

I just started Play framework(2.1) and copied sample project (Zentasks) and customising. I removed all the previous view, controller and model classes. When I run the app, my browser shows evolution script and I must run the script. But I do not want to create and execute this script because I have got already my database and tables before this app. \
In addition, there are still DDLs in the script creates tables already deleted.
I removed the evolutions directory again and again, the file auto generated and I did now work.

I want to understand how it works and know how to avoid this annoying?

Thanks.

Comment: I may find the answer: evolutionplugin=disabled in my conf file.

Answer (score 7):

There is commented option `evolutionplugin=disabled` in `application.conf` for this, just uncomment it:

```
# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
evolutionplugin=disabled
```

To make it working again, just comment it or set its value to `enabled`